# Given $f:A\to B\times C\times D$, how to define the set of all elements $a\in A$ such that the vector $f(a)$ has element $c’$ in its second entry?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be arbitrary sets with arbitrary elements $a\in A$, $b\in B$, $c\in C$ and $d\in D$. Further, let $f:A\to B\times C\times D$ be a function and take some element $c’\in C$.

**My goal is to define in set-builder notation the set of all elements $a\in A$ such that the vector $f(a)$ has element $c’$ in its second entry.** Since I’m planning on introducing this bit of notation in a formal definition, I need it to be as compact (i.e., short and precise) as possible. There go some things I have thought:

1. I have thought of using $\{a\in A:f_C(a)=c’\}$, but this notation seems incorrect because $f_C$ is the standard notation to denote something different (namely, the restriction of a function domain to some subset $C$).
2. I have thought of using $\{a\in A:\pi_C(f(a))=c’\}$, where $\pi_C$ is the “projection function”. Although I like this notation, I do not know how to define precisely the “projection function”. Could I perhaps define it as the function $\pi_C:A\times B\times C\to C$ satisfying $\pi_C(a,b,c)=c$? Also, in the context of this question, should the projection function be denoted $\pi_C$ (i.e., with uppercase subscript $C$) or $\pi_c$ (i.e., with lowercase subscript $c$)?

Comment: You should do (2). Probably $\pi_2:B\times C\times D\to C$ is better notation, defined by $\pi_2(b,c,d)=c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most compact I can think of is:
For $\pi_C\,:\,B\times C\times D \longrightarrow C$ the canonical projection
$$f^{-1}\big(\pi_C^{-1}(c')\big) \quad\text{or}\quad  (\pi_C \circ f)^{-1} ( c')$$

Answer (score 1):

$\{a\in A \mid f(a)=(b,c',d) \text{ for some } b\in B, d\in D\}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While I understand the notation you propose, it’s not compact enough for my purposes.